# Game Center inviting friends programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, invite, gkmatchmaker

I'm facing difficulty inviting a friend to the match.

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;
    request.playersToInvite = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"G:1102359306",nil ];


//  GKMatchmakerViewController *mv = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
//  [self presentModalViewController:mv animated:YES];


    [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog([error description]);
        }
        else if (match != nil) {NSLog(@"good match");
            //self.chatMatch = match;
            //self.chatMatch.delegate = self;       
            //[self chatReady];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"other error");
        }

    }];
```

The problem is I never receive the invitation notification on second device logged to the account - G:1102359306.
When I use GKMatchmakerViewController (uncomment above 2 lines) and comment GKMatchmaker block I have automatically checked the good friend - G:1102359306 and when I invites him the notification with accept/decline is shown, that's how I know it's correct.

Do you see anything wrong with the code above? I want to use my own UI to handle the multiplayer mode. The strange problem is I also don't see in console any logs good match/other error, and the [error description] is only printed when I call the above code twice - it says that the previous req was canceled.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot programmatically invite a specific set of players to a match.  The [`findMatchForRequest:withCompletionHandler:` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchmaker_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009593-CH1-SW2) says this:

> The match request’s `playersToInvite` property is ignored; to invite a specific set of players to the match, you must display a matchmaker view controller.

There is no public API that does what you want.

Comment: In iOS 6 you can now do this, i.e. the playersToInvite property is no longer ignored.

Comment: @sup that is true, however you still cannot programmatically intercept invites using handleInviteFromGameCenter as that call appear to be triggered only from the Game Center View Controllers.