# Inviting a Game Center friend to a match programmatically

Tags: game-center, gamekit

Does GameKit allow you to invite a specific Game Center friend to a match, programmatically, i.e. without presenting the GC ViewController?  The following handleInviteFromGameCenter documentation seems to imply that you can populate GKMatchRequest.playersToInvite and use it with [GKTurnBasedMatch findMatchForRequest]:

> When your delegate receives this message, **your application should create a new GKMatchRequest object and assign the playersToInvite parameter to the match request’s playersToInvite property. Then, your application can either call the GKTurnBasedMatch class method findMatchForRequest:withCompletionHandler: to find a match programmatically** or it can use the request to instantiate a new GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController to show a user interface to the player.

But I'm finding that when findMatchForRequest calls my completion block with the populated match, the GameCenter ID I passed to it is not set as the 2nd player.  Instead it's empty and the status is "matching".  And therefore, when I call endTurnWithNextParticipant, it succeeds, but the invite isn't received on my 2nd device.  This illustrates what I'm doing:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
request.playersToInvite = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: otherPlayerGCID,nil ];

[GKTurnBasedMatch findMatchForRequest:request 
                  withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error) 
{
    if (error) 
        NSLog(@"returned from fimdmatch but with error");
    else if (match != nil) {
        NSLog(@"match returned success and match populated");
        NSArray* otherPlayers = [match participants];
        if (otherPlayers.count>1) {
           NSData* placeholder = [@"no data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           [match endTurnWithNextParticipant:[otherPlayers objectAtIndex:1] 
                  matchData:placeholder 
                  completionHandler:^(NSError *error) 
           {
              if (error) 
                 NSLog(@"returned from END TURN but with error");
              else
                 NSLog(@"returned from  END TURN successfully");
           }];     

        }
     }
     else
        System::log("match returned success but match NOT populated");
}];
```

And like the person who seems to be having a similar problem here  [Game Center inviting friends progammatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4117781/497357), if I insert a call to the view controller, in my case GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController, all seems to work.

Thanks.

UPDATED:
I did see in an Apple Developer's presentation on turn-based GC, a mention of something like, "If you want to invite a GC friend, we ask that you go through the GC view controller.

Any insight appreciated.  Thanks again.

Comment: Does this still work in iOS9? I've just asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728503/gkmatchmaker-findmatchforrequest-invite-never-received

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wanted to share what I learned on this: As of iOS 5 there is not a way to invite a game center friend to play a game without going through the pre-defined GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController flow, which is optimized for starting a match in real time, guiding the user through three different screens.

After being urged to do so by apple dev support, I did submit a feature request to be able to invoke a simple, one-page view controller that would allow the user to send an invite / "recommend game" message via game center.

**UPDATE FOR iOS 6:** 
Happy to report that it looks like this has been addressed in iOS 6.  My original programmatic (non-UI) example above now works as originally expected.

Comment: Drat! I am in the same situation, and I was hoping that this wasn't the case.

Comment: Thanks for the update, just tripped over that little lack of documentation on GKTurnBasedMatch myself :(  Strange though because I have YatzyAddict App and this doesnt seem to use a standard view controller for the multi-player.  I was first thinking it was just a limitation of the sandbox.

Comment: If it's not using a standard view controller, it's probably not using GKMatchmaker to find matches.  I actually contacted the dev team for Carcassonne and they confirmed that they are using their own system.

Comment: This is again an issue on iOS 9 GM -- if you specify a player ID on the request playersToInvite, you'll end up with participants with nil player ID and status GKTurnBasedParticipantStatusMatching. The solution is to use "recipients" with a list of GKPlayer objects.

Comment: `playersToInvite` was deprecated in iOS 8. Use `recipients` instead.